Why is the group membership problem hard for general matrices but not for the stabilizer group?
In this answer, it is claimed that the problem of answering whether an invertible matrix $A$ is an element of the group $\langle B_1, B_2,..., B_n\rangle$ for invertible matrices $B_i$ is in NP.
For stabilizers, this does not appear to be the case. Let $\langle S_1, S_2, ... S_n\rangle$ be a stabilizer group. To check if a Pauli operator $P$ is a member of the group or not seems to be possible through some tableau manipulation and Gaussian elimination.
Is this indeed true and if so, what is the reason why the general group membership problem is hard but the stabilizer group membership problem is not?

Do you mean NP-hard?

A tableau can be interpreted as a stabilizer state but it can also be interpreted as a Clifford operation. The analog of the invertible matrix group problem would be the Clifford group problem, not the stabilizer group problem.
Yes, Gaussian elimination works for telling if stabilizers can be reached from a set of generators.
